# Azure Databricks is there a way to export schema and create table statements similar to SQL Management Studio?

Tags: schema, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

Azure Databricks is there a way to export schema and create table statements similar to SQL Management Studio either in python or sql?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` SQL command for that ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-aux-show-create-table.html)). For example:

```
schema = spark.sql("SHOW CREATE TABLE airlinedata").collect()[0][0]
print(schema)
```

may give this output:

```sql
CREATE TABLE default.airlinedata (
  city STRING,
  state STRING,
  country STRING,
  IATA STRING)
USING delta
PARTITIONED BY (country)
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'delta.minReaderVersion' = '1',
  'delta.minWriterVersion' = '2')
```